# Dagger 2 Inject Fragment with dependency from Activity Module - matching key exists

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Using the Dagger 2.11 Dagger* classes I can't seem to provide my Fragments with dependencies declared in the parent Activities module.

I get the following error:

```
Error:(21, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] 
@javax.inject.Named("ENTITY_KEY") java.lang.String cannot be provided 
without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
@javax.inject.Named("ENTITY_KEY") java.lang.String is injected at
com.cragchat.mobile.ui.view.fragments.CommentSectionFragment.mEntityKey
com.cragchat.mobile.ui.view.fragments.CommentSectionFragment is injected at
com.cragchat.mobile.ui.view.activity.RouteActivity.commentSectionFragment
com.cragchat.mobile.ui.view.activity.RouteActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
A binding with matching key exists in component: 
com.cragchat.mobile.di.ActivityBinding_AreaActivity.AreaActivitySubcomponent
```

As I understand this error, Dagger recognizes that there is a dependency of the correct key but it's in the AreaActivitySubcomponent which for some reason is not reachable by the CommentSecctionFragment subcomponent.

ApplicationComponent.java:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ActivityBinding.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends 
AndroidInjector<CragChatApplication> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    ApplicationComponent.Builder application(Application application);

    ApplicationComponent build();
}

void inject(CragChatApplication app);
}
```

ActivityBinding.java:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBinding {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity mainActivity();

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {AreaModule.class, 
         AreaFragmentsModule.class})
    abstract AreaActivity areaActivity();
}
```

AreaModule.java

```
@Module
public class AreaModule {

@Provides
Area provideArea(AreaActivity activity) {
    return activity.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NavigationUtil.ENTITY);
}

@Provides
@Named(InjectionNames.ENTITY_KEY)
String entityKey(Area area) {
    return area.getKey();
}

@Provides
@Named(InjectionNames.AREA_IDS)
String[] areaIds(Area area) {
    return area.getSubAreas().toArray(new String[area.getSubAreas().size()]);
}

@Provides
@Named(InjectionNames.ROUTE_IDS)
String[] routeIds(Area area) {
    return area.getRoutes().toArray(new String[area.getRoutes().size()]);
}

}
```

AreaFragmentsModule.java

```
@Module
public abstract class AreaFragmentsModule {

@FragmentScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract RecentActivityFragment recentActivityFragment();

@FragmentScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract AreaListFragment areaListFragment();

@FragmentScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract CommentSectionFragment commentSectionFragment();

@FragmentScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract ImageFragment imageFragment();

}
```

CommentSectionFragment.java:

```
public class CommentSectionFragment extends DaggerFragment implements 
View.OnClickListener {

/* -------------  This injection causes the error!!!!! ------------ */
@Inject
@Named(InjectionNames.ENTITY_KEY)
String mEntityKey;

/*
    Repository and Authentication inject correctly from ApplicationModule
*/
@Inject
Repository mRepository;

@Inject
Authentication mAuthentication;

@Inject
public CommentSectionFragment() {
}

/* .... */
}
```

Comment: hi, I am also facing the same problem the method is identified but its not reachable from the other module. Have you solved the issue and kindly check my issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55892748/4111151