# Dagger-android build errror cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am learning dagger dependency injection(I know i am late to the party, its better to start now).

But I am facing below error. Please any help or suggestion could be greatly appreciated.

**ERROR Log**

```
    error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] @com.mypackage.di.key.ItemDetail java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<RetailShopApplication> {
   ^
  @com.mypackage.di.key.ItemDetail java.lang.Integer is injected at
      com.mypackage.ui.detail.ItemDetailViewModel.<init>(…, itemId)
  com.mypackage.ui.detail.ItemDetailViewModel is injected at
      com.mypackage.di.module.ViewModelModule.provideItemDetailViewModel(itemDetailViewModel)
  java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
      com.mypackage.viewModel.ViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
  com.mypackage.viewModel.ViewModelFactory is injected at
      com.mypackage.ui.home.ItemCategoryFragment.itemViewFactory
  com.mypackage.ui.home.ItemCategoryFragment is injected at
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
component path: com.mypackage.di.component.ApplicationComponent ? com.mypackage.di.builder.ActivityBuilder_ContributeHomeActivity.HomeActivitySubcomponent ? com.mypackage.ui.home.HomeFragmentProvider_ContributeItemCategoryFragment.ItemCategoryFragmentSubcomponent
```

**My Problem**

> I created a provideItemDetailViewModel() with contributeAndroidInjection annotation in ViewModelModule but the ItemDetailViewModel contructor has an integer value.
>
> So i am providing an integer value at runtime from my activity intent
>   through ItemDetailActivityModule class. Problem is dagger throwing me
>   an error "integer already exist in the scope" but not able to inject
>   in the ViewModel contructor.

**ViewModelModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(ItemCategoryViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel provideItemCategoryViewModel(ItemCategoryViewModel 
itemCategoryViewModel);

@Binds
@IntoMap//<---- Here is the new ViewModel
@ViewModelKey(ItemDetailViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel provideItemDetailViewModel(ItemDetailViewModel 
itemDetailViewModel);

@Binds
abstract ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory 
getViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
}
```

**ItemDetailViewModel**

```
@Inject
  public ItemDetailViewModel(Application application, @ItemDetail int itemId) 
  {
        itemRepository = new ItemRepository(application);
        itemLiveData = itemRepository.getItem(itemId);
    }
```

**ItemDetailActivityModule**

```
@Module
public class ItemDetailActivityModule {

  @Provides
  @ItemDetail
  int provideItemId(ItemDetailActivity itemDetailActivity) {
    return itemDetailActivity.getIntent().getIntExtra(AppConstants.ITEM_ID, 
  0);
  }

}
```

**ActivityBuilder**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {HomeFragmentProvider.class, 
HomeActivityModule.class})
abstract HomeActivity contributeHomeActivity();

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = ItemDetailActivityModule.class)
abstract ItemDetailActivity contributeItemDetailActivity();

}
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, 
ApplicationModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends 
AndroidInjector<RetailShopApplication> {

  @Component.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends 
  AndroidInjector.Builder<RetailShopApplication> {
  }

}
```

**ApplicationModule**

```
@Module(includes = ViewModelModule.class)
public class ApplicationModule {

   @Provides
   Application provideApplication(RetailShopApplication application) {
    return application;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Problem is i was creating provider for each ViewModel in ViewModelModule class which is included in AppModule.

Every Activity created using @ContributeAndroidInjection is a sub component.

So App component and Activity sub component are different. Activity component can access provider of App component but its not vice versa that the reason for **injection already exist error**

I solved the problem my including view model inside the activity module instead of appcomponent module.

### ViewModelModule

**Before**

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

   @Binds
   @IntoMap//<---- Here is the new ViewModel
   @ViewModelKey(ItemDetailViewModel.class)
   abstract ViewModel provideItemDetailViewModel(ItemDetailViewModel 
   itemDetailViewModel);

   @Binds
   abstract ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory 
   getViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
}
```

**After** - Only ViewModelFactory is necessary in ViewModelModule move all your ViewModel provider to activity module.

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

   @Binds
   abstract ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory 
   getViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
}
```

### ItemDetailProvider

Create Abstract class in order to hold the ViewModel providers

```
@Module
public abstract class ItemDetailProvider {

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(ItemDetailViewModel.class)
  abstract ViewModel provideItemDetailViewModel(ItemDetailViewModel 
  itemDetailViewModel);

}
```

### ActivityModule

Now add the created provider in the Activity module as shown below

**Before**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

   @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = 
   {ItemDetailActivityModule.class})
   abstract ItemDetailActivity contributeItemDetailActivity();

}
```

**After** - Now add the ViewModel that corespond to the above activity in my case it is
ItemDetailViewModel class

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

   @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = 
   {ItemDetailActivityModule.class,ItemDetailProvider.class})//<--- provider added in this line
   abstract ItemDetailActivity contributeItemDetailActivity();

}
```